# Which philosopher was Jonathan named after?

Tags: glasslip

In the last episode, it was revealed that the chickens all shared their names with famous philosophers.

- Husserl
- Confucius
- Roger
- Makuzu
- Jonathan.

[image]

I was able to find most of the references fairly easily, but the origin of Jonathan's name eludes me:

- **Edmun Husserl**, who established the school of *phenomenology*

  [image: Edmun Husserl]
- **Confucius**, the very famous Chinese philosopher.

  [image: Confucius]
- **Roger Bacon**, a Franciscan friar who placed considerable emphasis on the study of nature through empirical methods.

  [image: Roger Bacon]
- **Tadano Makuzu**, a poet and philosopher who wrote important commentaries on Japan's social and political problems.

  [image: Tadano Makuzu]

Which philosopher was Jonathan - presumably the central chicken in the above picture - named after?

I was able to find several philosophers named Jonathan, but most of them are still alive, and much more recent than the other philosophers.

Comment: Maybe it was [Jonathan Edwards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Edwards_%28theologian%29)?

Comment: A user in the [Philosophy chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17940881#17940881) suggested that it might have something to do with [Jonathan Livingston Seagull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Livingston_Seagull), along with other two contemporary philosophers.

Comment: @JNat It could be Jonathan Edwards - I think Jonathan Livingston Seagull is unlikely though as he is fictional and also much more modern than the other choices of names

Comment: My impression of the last episode is that Jonathan is *not* named after a philosopher; I believe they implied he's named after an adventurer. The best explanation I've seen for this is that Jonathan is somehow related to Kakeru, while the other four are related to Touko's other friends.

Comment: Perhaps Johnathan Joestar? He's had some *bizarre* adventures...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that all the chickens are related to Touko's friends, it becomes quite obvious who Jonathan is meant to represent.

Kakeru reminds Touko of Michelangelo's "David" and is often referred to by that name. In the Biblical story of David, his best friend is a man named Jonathan.

Jonathan is not a philosopher, but in the same way, Kakeru is not friends with Touko's other friends. It separates him from the others and Touko does pay more attention to that chicken.